# Establish relationship between two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel document like this:

```
   Cat1  Cat2  Cat3  SubCat1  SubCat2  SubCat3   SubCat4

P1  T                            T

P2        T            T                  T

P3              T                                   T
```

I would like to find a relationship between catagories and sub catagories based on the product belonging to them like this:

```
       SubCat1  SubCat2  SubCat3  SubCat4
Cat1               X

Cat2      X                 X

Cat3                                 X
```

Is there a formula to achieve this?

Comment: I am not sure how you have arrived at the bottom table being derived from the top. I don't see any immediate logical relationship. Perhaps explain this logic and why P doesn't appear in the bottom table (or referenced in relation to bottom table) and include your attempts to solve so far. For now..I am voting to close as unclear.

Comment: Hi @QHarr, the relationship between category and sub category is through the product they belong. For example, if we look at the first table, P1 belongs to Cat1 and SubCat2 and hence you see that in second table, the 'X' mark is placed at the intersection of Cat1 and SubCat2. I am looking for a formula to achieve this programmatically due to large data size.

Comment: I apologise  though I think you might want to add a little more explanation to your question. You want to plot all the products cat subcat relations on the bottom table. It then seems that P is somewhat irrelevant unless it can appear more than once?

Comment: Can each item be matched to a single category and a single sub-category?

Comment: ^^ that is what I was getting at. Thanks @GalAbra

Comment: Hi @QHarr. You guys got it correct. Basically to match category and sub category of each products and then establish the relationship between them. I would like to find out if sub category 2 belongs to category 1 or 2. There may be cases of products belonging to multiple sub categories but they can only belong to single category. HTH.

Comment: @GalAbra yes that is correct.

Comment: Some form of index and match in the bottom table then might work though on mobile at present so can’t think it through properly.

Comment: Good question, +1, except that you didn't try anything yourself, which is why I'm guessing you got the downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
= IF(SUMPRODUCT((INDEX($B$2:$D$4,0,MATCH($A7,$B$1:$D$1,0))="T")*
                (INDEX($E$2:$H$4,0,MATCH(B$6,$E$1:$H$1,0))="T"))>0,"X","")
```

Obviously, update your cell ranges accordingly.

I have this formula in cell `B7` and dragged it to cell `E9`.

See below for working example.

[image]